# Is it possible to model polar coordinates in WebGL

Tags: webgl, cad, polar-coordinates

I want to convert a set of coordinates into polar coordinates (the easy part), and then model them on a polar 3D grid. Is this possible using WebGL or are only Cartesian coordinates supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement any type of coordinate transform you want in shaders. However, there is an important restriction:

If you draw two connected vertices (i.e. a straight line, or the edge of a triangle), *the result will always be a straight line on the screen* — it is not possible to do otherwise in OpenGL.

The Cartesian-polar transform turns straight lines into curved lines. This means that if you want to transform a straight-sided shape and get the “right” curved result, you must draw it using a sequence of closely-spaced vertices — as many as you need to produce the “resolution” of smooth curvature you want. This is generally not hard to program, but it is something to be aware of.

Comment: there are other ways to draw in GL though. See http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cloop/loopblinn05.pdf

Comment: I want to not only input polar coordinates but also use them for transformations. I would leave out the translation transformation and essentially redefine the transformation matrix. Is this possible?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what you want: Yes. It's all just arithmetic, and there is no restriction on what kind of arithmetic you can do in a shader.

Comment: well for rotation, its all matrix multiplication. I want to change the transformation matrix from one that rotates cartesian coordinates to one that rotates polar coordinates

Comment: There is no requirement that you use matrices at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shaders in webgl so you can give your inputs as polar coordinates and have webgl transform them to cartesian internally.